# Why does the generator get rewound to its beginning?

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to implement a function that does this:

Rotate a 2D infinite array by 45 degrees of a full turn, clockwise (this question is taken from [www.codewars.com](http://www.codewars.com)).

For example (generators are represented with list notation):

```
rotate([[1,2,3,4,...],
        ['a','b','c',...],
        ['A','B',...],
        ['0',...],
        ...])
    == [[1],
        ['a',2],
        ['A','b',3],
        ['0','B','c',4],
        ...]
```

Inputs/outputs will be infinite generators of infinite generators. My solution is this:

```
def rotate(seq):
    row = 0
    generators = []
    while True:
        next_gen = next(seq)
        generators.append(next_gen)
        yield inner_generator(row, generators)
        row += 1


def inner_generator(row, arr):
    while row >= 0:
        next_value = next(arr[row])
        row -= 1
        yield next_value
```

However, the generators within the list `generators` get rewound to their beginning. For example, when the input is as in the example above, my function returns:

```
[[1], ['a', 1], ['A', 'a', 1], ['0', 'A', 'a', 1], ...]
```

instead of:

```
[[1], ['a', 2], ['A', 'b', 3], ['0', 'B', 'c', 4], ...]
```

What's the reason for this?

My simple test is:

```
def gen_chars():
    def gen_row(j):
        while True:
            yield from j
    
    for k in ['1234', 'abc', 'AB', '0']:
        yield gen_row(k)



seq1 = gen_chars()
seq2 = rotate(seq1)
g1 = next(seq2)
g2 = next(seq2)


for i in g2:
    print(i)
```

and it prints (as the content of the second generator, for instance) ['a', 1] intstead of ['a', 2].

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your code.  As it is, it will only return generators (not the output you are describing).  Also, the issue may reside in the input provided to the rotate() function, which cannot be a list of lists as you indicated.  Please provide a usable example (that we can copy/paste and run) that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce. This sounds like you screwed up your `rotate` input.

Comment: Note that it is not actually possible to rewind a generator.

Comment: Your `gen_row` function says `while True: yield from j` where `j` is a string when you call it - so you are yielding every character from the string, within a `while True` loop, hence you are yielding every character infinitely many times.